# swipelistview setOnClickListener dismiss

Tags: android, swipe

I'm using the 47deg/android-swipelistview and i use the mode SWIPE_ACTION_DISMISS perfectly.

But in another activity and i need to use SWIPE_ACTION_REVEAL with a delete button.
So to delete an element, in the adapter i do that:

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
    final int pos = position;
    final View conv = convertView;
    final ViewGroup par = parent;
    //View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.afficheitem_swipecontact, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.bloquer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bloquer);


        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    ((SwipeListView)parent).recycle(convertView, position);
    // Get item

    BeanMembre membre = (BeanMembre) getItem(position);

    holder.membreName.setText(membre.getPseudo());





    holder.bloquer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, R.string.bloquer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            listMembre.remove(pos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });




    return convertView;
```

When i do that, the element is removed but the item of the list is not refresh. I have to scroll down and up to see the new element.
I didn't find on the web, on stack or in the sample a way to do that.

Have you alerady do that ? have you a sample ? Do i need to call dismiss method from the adapter to generate dismiss animation ?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post more adapter code ?

Comment: done, i added the getView method but i delete some stuff because my  adapter is big. But we can see just the necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Please see the solution below

```
holder.supprimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.supprimer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //we can call dismmiss method like this.
    ((SwipeListView)par).dismiss(pos,true);
    }
});
```